# Como extrair dados para os campos Models.py do Scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

Pretendo retirar todos os "Municipios" da tag  começando nesta página.
https://www.anmp.pt/anmp/pro/mun1/mun101w3.php?cod=M2200

E em seguida retirar informações como: "nome do concelho", "presidente da câmara", etc. das páginas de cada concelho da lista.

Utilizando a shell consigo linha a linha extrair toda a informação. Problema é na hora de por a spider a funcionar.

```
#Spider.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import urlparse
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from municipios.items import Municipio
import time


class GetmunSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'getMun'
    allowed_domains = ['anmp.pt']
    start_urls = ['https://www.anmp.pt/anmp/pro/mun1/mun101w3.php?cod=M2200']

    def municipio_attr(self, response):
        municipios_url = response.xpath('//select/option/@value').extract()
        for municipio in municipios_url:
            full_url = ['https://www.anmp.pt/anmp/pro/mun1/{0}'.format(i) for i in municipios_url]      
            yield FormRequest.from_response(str(full_url), callback=self.parse) 

    def parse(self, response):

    #dados do municipio
    municipio = ItemLoader(item = Municipio(), response = response)
    municipio.add_xpath('nome', '//div[@class="sel3"]/text()'.extract())
    municipio.add_xpath('pres_camara', '//div[@class="f3"]/text()')[3].extract().split(",")[0]
    municipio.add_xpath('pres_assembleia', '//div[@class="f3"]/text()')[4].extract().split(",")[0]
    municipio.add_xpath('contacto', '//div[@class="sel2"]/text()').extract()
    municipio.add_value('endereco', " ".join(contacto)[:-42])
    municipio.add_value('telefone', contacto[2])
    municipio.add_value('fax', contacto[3])

    return Municipio.load_item()
```

o campo **contacto** só foi criado para poder retirar o telefone e o fax da mesma html tag

```
#Item.py
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Municipio(scrapy.Item):
    nome = scrapy.Field()
    pres_camara = scrapy.Field()
    pres_assembleia = scrapy.Field()
    endereco = scrapy.Field()
    telefone = scrapy.Field()
    fax = scrapy.Field()
```

Embora o Scrapy nao apresente nenhum erro no final, so consigo fazer passar a tabela com os varios campos, que mesmo assim aparecem pela ordem errada.

[image: site, items.py, spiders.py]

Tenho procurado na documentação do Scrapy e em varias sites e tutoriais mas sem sucesso.

Alguém me consegue apontar na direcção certa?
Obrigado!
Carlos

Comment: Olá Carlos. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Por favor, faça sua pergunta em português aqui. Para perguntas em inglês, poste no [SO]. Recomendo que faça o [tour] do nosso site para esclarecer eventuais dúvidas.

Comment: ok. Obrigado quando fiz a pergunta pensei que estava a postar no site em ingles.